# Luarocks luasql-mysql compile error

Tags: c++, mysql, lua

My computer environment is:

- Win7Pro 64bit
- VS2015
- LuaForWindows_v5.1.5-52.exe
- luarocks-2.4.4-win32
- mysql-installer-community-5.5.60.1.msi(x86)

How can I solve the error shown below during installation of `luasql-mysql`? How do I resolve the problem at the command prompt?

```
c:\Lua\5.1>luarocks install luasql-mysql
MYSQL_INCDIR="C:\MySQL\ConnectorC\inclu de"
MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:\MySQL\ConnectorC\lib" Installing
http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/luasql-mysql-2.3.5-1.rockspec.
.. Cloning into 'luasql'... remote: Counting objects: 2530, done.
remote: Total 2530 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 2530R
cts:  99% (2505/2530), 636.01 KiB | 282.00 KiB/s Receiving objects:
100% (2530/2530), 646.09 KiB | 270.00 KiB/s, done. Resolving deltas:
100% (1524/1524), done. Note: checking out 'v2.3.5'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing
another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you
may do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again.
Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 2f2c4eb Rockspecs for new version. cl /MD /O2 -c
-Fosrc/luasql.obj -IC:/Lua/5.1/include src/luasql.c -IC:\MySQL\Con nectorC\include x86용 Microsoft (R) C/C++ 최적화 컴파일러 버전 19.00.24215.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

luasql.c cl /MD /O2 -c -Fosrc/ls_mysql.obj -IC:/Lua/5.1/include
src/ls_mysql.c -IC:\MySQL \ConnectorC\include x86용 Microsoft (R) C/C++
최적화 컴파일러 버전 19.00.24215.1 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All
rights reserved.

ls_mysql.c link -dll -def:luasql/mysql.def -out:luasql/mysql.dll
C:/Lua/5.1/lib/lua5.1.lib src/luasql.obj src/ls_mysql.obj
-libpath:C:\MySQL\ConnectorC\lib mysqlclient.lib

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1 Copyright (C)
Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

luasql/mysql.lib 라이브러리 및 luasql/mysql.exp 개체를 생성하고 있습니다.
mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2019: __imp__RegCloseKey@4 외부
기호(참 조 위치: _win32_have_tcpip 함수)에서 확인하지 못했습니다.
mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2019: __imp__RegEnumValueA@32
외부 기호( 참조 위치: _win_init_registry 함수)에서 확인하지 못했습니다.
mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2019: __imp__RegOpenKeyExA@20
외부 기호( 참조 위치: _win32_have_tcpip 함수)에서 확인하지 못했습니다.
mysqlclient.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2019: __imp__EqualSid@8 외부
기호(참조 위 치: "public: bool __thiscall Sid::operator==(class Sid const
&)" (??8Sid@@QAE_NA BV0@@Z) 함수)에서 확인하지 못했습니다.
mysqlclient.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2019:
__imp__GetTokenInformation@20 외부 기호(참조 위치: "public: __thiscall Sid::Sid(void *)" (??0Sid@@QAE@PAX@Z) 함수) 에서 확인하지 못했습니다.
mysqlclient.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2019: __imp__IsValidSid@4 외부
기호(참조 위치: "public: __thiscall Sid::Sid(void *)" (??0Sid@@QAE@PAX@Z)
함수)에서 확인하 지 못했습니다. mysqlclient.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2019:
__imp__LookupAccountNameW@28 외부 기호(참조 위치: "public: __thiscall Sid::Sid(wchar_t const *)" (??0Sid@@QAE@PB_W @Z) 함수)에서 확인하지 못했습니다.
mysqlclient.lib(random.obj) : error LNK2019:
__imp__CryptAcquireContextA@20 외부  기호(참조 위치: "public: __thiscall TaoCrypt::OS_Seed::OS_Seed(void)" (??0OS_Se ed@TaoCrypt@@QAE@XZ) 함수)에서
확인하지 못했습니다. mysqlclient.lib(random.obj) : error LNK2019:
__imp__CryptReleaseContext@8 외부 기호(참조 위치: "public: __thiscall TaoCrypt::OS_Seed::~OS_Seed(void)" (??1OS_Se ed@TaoCrypt@@QAE@XZ)
함수)에서 확인하지 못했습니다. mysqlclient.lib(random.obj) : error LNK2019:
__imp__CryptGenRandom@12 외부 기호( 참조 위치: "public: __thiscall TaoCrypt::RandomNumberGenerator::RandomNumberGene rator(void)"
(??0RandomNumberGenerator@TaoCrypt@@QAE@XZ) 함수)에서 확인하지 못했 습니다.
luasql/mysql.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 10개의 확인할 수 없는 외부 참조입니다.

Error: Build error: Failed installing luasql/mysql.dll in
C:\Lua\5.1\rocks/luasq l-mysql/2.3.5-1/lib/luasql

c:\Lua\5.1>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: - mysql 64bit change to 32bit. version down. (it's disapear 32/64bit error)

- C:\MySQL\ConnectorC\lib\vs14\mysqlclient.lib copy to C:\MySQL\ConnectorC\lib folder.

- Running to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat before luarocks.

- Administrator Command Line

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The first error you are receiving is a linker error. The compiler is not finding files that it needs to successfully build. See [Linker Tools Error LNK2019](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx) for details.

Comment: i already read your answer at other article.
I need solution at the DOS command line. (ex. cl.exe, link.exe ???)